# Error Call Function On Yii2 Dropdown Active Form

Tags: javascript, yii2

Halo, I using Yii2 and I get error while call a function in dropdown list.

This is my dropdown :

```
<?= $form->field($model, "jenis_manifest")->dropDownList([ 'Berangkat' => 'Berangkat', 'Pulang' => 'Pulang'], ['onchange' => 'fungsiUtama();', 'class' => 'form-control', 'prompt' => '-- Manifest --']) ?>
```

And this is my script :

```
<?php

    $script = <<<JS
    function fungsiUtama()
    {
        alert("Hello");
    }
    JS;

    $this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

I also try with JsExpression base on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773795/onchange-function-in-dropdownlist-yii2), but still not working.

This is the error what I get :
[image]

Comment: Try with `$this->registerJs($script, \yii\web\View::POS_END);`

Comment: thanks, its working. but I still don't know the different..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$this->registerJs($script, \yii\web\View::POS_END);
```

The last part means - add this script straightforward at the end of page.

Without the second function argument the default one is called -
 `\yii\web\View::POS_READY` - which means - add this script wrapped in `jQuery(document).ready()` method that forces scripts to wait untill the page's DOM is fully loaded. Before that your script is unavailable and that is probably why you've got this error.

Comment: Hi, one question again, if I put the function under `JQuery(document).ready`, is it possible to call it from `onchange` ??

Comment: I'm not sure, it may be necessary to be available immediately so in this case - not. On the other hand you can always add jQuery trigger for on change and then you don't have to use `onchange` HTML attribute.